# How to use ImportXML to extract text within <span> with multiple classes?

Tags: google-sheets, discord, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google spreadsheet's ImportXML function, trying to fetch member counts from discordapp.com's invite link so that I can keep track on multiple servers' size and growth. The desired text is inside a **span** inside other **div**s. From what I've read, I'd think my code would work, but the error says content is empty. See details below:

[image: ImportXML attempt]

My attempted code:

```
=ImportXML("https://discordapp.com/invite/steam","//span[@class='pillMessage-1btqlx medium-zmzTW- size16-14cGz5 height20-mO2eIN']")
```

- Expected: Cell filled with current count, "24,013 Members".
- Preferably: Cell filled with value 24013.
- Actually: Cell: **#N/A** & Hovering: **Error**  **Imported content is empty.**

[image: Error, imported content is empty]

How can I fix it to fetch the server's member count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

It seems that at the site, the value like `24,013` is shown by the script. So the value cannot be directly retrieved by `IMPORTXML()`. But when I saw the HTML, it was found that the value is included in the metadata of HTML. In this answer, as a workaround, the value is retrieved from the metadata. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified formula:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[3]/@content"),"hang out with ([0-9,]+) "))
```

- The url of `https://discordapp.com/invite/steam` is put to the cell "A1".
- Content of metadata is retrieved using `IMPORTXML()`.

  - In this case, I used `//meta[3]/@content` as the xpath.
- The value is retrieved using `REGEXEXTRACT()`.
- The value is converted to the number using `VALUE()`.

#### Result:

When I tried above formula, `24018` was retrieved.

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.